# What are these brass spacers on a simple porcelain drawer pull called?

Tags: screws, knobs, pull

I have a few of these vintage, small, round porcelain drawer pulls; see pics below. Some have screws and “spacers” but some don’t. So I’m trying to figure out what those brass “spacers” might officially be called so I can buy some more of them. What the heck might be their official name?

Yes, maybe they are simply called “spacers” but when I try to search for “brass spacers” online I’m simply getting results for hex-shaped spacers that typically are used in PC cases and similar gear. Utterly not what this thing is.

From what I can see they basically act like big washers; they have no threads internally. They simply are used to make the knob stand off a bit from the thing — typically wood with a hole in it — for the same reason washers are used; to provide a protective middle surface.

[image: Porcelain pull with screw and spacer attached.] [image: The brass spacer itself; top view.] [[image: The brass spacer itself; side view.3]

Comment: I'd suggest you'll have better luck finding them by visiting a local "architectural salvage" yard. Instead of throwing everything away, people are carefully disassembling old houses now and selling off the old doors, hinges, cabinets, drawers, pulls, etc. You'll be amazed at the things you'll find there. You'll most likely need the services of the proprietor or a sales person to find what you're looking for, but they'll lead you there in seconds.

Comment: @FreeMan Oh, believe me… I know about those places. But I live in NYC and sadly because of COVID-19, places like that are closed. How exactly can you reopen a place where everyone is touching things all the time in an era of constant disinfection? That said, I did an eBay search for local salvagers who are selling pulls and… et viola! I found someone in New Jersey who had a lot of drawer pull parts that are a perfect match for these things. So hey! It all worked out.

Comment: Glad to hear you found what you needed. Sad to hear the city is still in such a state of fear and panic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That item is known as a “knob base stem.”